# How to avoid Infinite Loop in vue.js watcher and socket.io

Tags: vue.js, socket.io, vuejs2

I have bulma slider on client side with vue.js and socket.io. In my case I would have few instances of clients - if somebody moves his slider socket.io start sending message to server (json file) server saves this status and broadcasting this json to others. Problem is when others recives messages - they started sending this json too, because data value on their instances changes too.

Thanks for help

```
<template>
<div>
<input class="slider is-fullwidth is-large is-danger" step="3" min="0" max="255" v-model="value" type="range" v-bind:disabled="disabled">
<p>{{value}}</p>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data: function () {
    return {
      value: 0,
      disabled: false
    }
  },

methods: {
 sendChange: function () {
  this.$socket.send({io: "io1", mode: "brightness", user: "tomek", param: this.value})
 },
},

watch: {
 value: function (val) {
  this.sendChange()
 }
},

sockets: {
 dataFromServer: function (data) {
  this.value = data.param
  },
 },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind action to an event, like `@input` or `@change` insted of `v-model` value, get rid of watcher and try something like this:

```
<input class="..."
       step="3"
       min="0"
       max="255"
       v-model="value"
       type="range"
       :disabled="disabled"
       @input="sendChange()">
```

This way you send request only when user intentionally changes his value, not when value updates by any mean.